# Check whether a newly created object is unique by several fields

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I have to check a submitted form against the existing database to make sure it is not duplicated by the combination of several fields, say supplier_id, invoice_no and amount.

Is there a built-in method or should I write a code myself? If so - what are guidelines: where to put it, what are the good practices?

At the moment I am extending the CRUD controller and overwriting the createAction adding the condition there. Not sure whether this method is a good practice.

Comment: Have a look at [UniqueEntity](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html) constraint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity\User;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @UniqueEntity({"name", "email"}, message="This value is in a database.")
 */
class User
{

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name;

    /*
     * @var string
     */
    protected $email;
    ...
}
```